# How to copy row cell values from a JTable and transfer to another JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to get the values from the row cells on my first table and transfer it to my second table in a button click, but I fail to make it happen. I tried using `for` loop to evenly assign each row indexes, but it only adds a row twice with repeating cell values. Here is my code below.

```
int mainTRow = mainTable.getRowCount();
JButton totBTN = new JButton("Total");
totBTN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DefaultTableModel mdl = (DefaultTableModel)mainTable.getModel();
        DefaultTableModel mdl1 = (DefaultTableModel)showTable.getModel();
        mdl1.setRowCount(mainTRow);
        for(int i1=0; i1<mainTRow; i1++) {
            mdl1.setRowCount(mainTRow);
            mdl1.addRow(new Object[] {mainTable.getValueAt(i1,0)});
            mdl1.setValueAt(mdl.getValueAt(i1,0), i1, 0 );                  
        }
        
    }
});
totBTN.setBounds(365, 341, 89, 23);
mainPanel.add(totBTN);
```

I just want to clarify that `mainTable` here is the first table and `showTable` is the second one

Comment: Any reason why they can't share the same model

Comment: All rows ? means all data from one table to another? or any specific row?

Comment: Just a specific row and its cells

Comment: what about like `sql`? just run a `sql` command in button actionperformed instead of copy?

Comment: No need for invoking the `setRowCount(...)` method. When you invoke the addRow(....) method the model will manage the row count. Generally the only reason to invoke the setRowCount() method is to set the row count to 0 to clear the model so you can add completely new data. Also, why are you invoking setValueAt(...). The  addRow(...) method already adds the data to the model, so why would you try to change its value if you are doing a copy of the existing data? Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

At a very simplistic level, you could just do something like...

```
int[] selectedRows = leftTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();
for (int row : selectedRows) {
    int modelRow = leftTable.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
    rightModel.addRow(leftModel.getDataVector().get(modelRow));
}
```

If your models are use different structures, then you need to convert the data between, for example, if I change the `rightModel` to...

```
private DefaultTableModel rightModel = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Name"}, 0);
```

I'd then need to do something more like...

```
int[] selectedRows = leftTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();
for (int row : selectedRows) {
    int modelRow = leftTable.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
    String firstName = (String)leftModel.getValueAt(row, 0);
    String lastName = (String)leftModel.getValueAt(row, 1);
    rightModel.addRow(new Object[] {lastName + " " + firstName});
}
```

*nb: This is just copying the selected rows*

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        private DefaultTableModel leftModel = new DefaultTableModel(NAMES, new String[] {"First", "Last"});
        private DefaultTableModel rightModel = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"First", "Last"}, 0);

        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JTable leftTable = new JTable(leftModel);
            JTable rightTable = new JTable(rightModel);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            JButton copyToRight = new JButton(">");
            copyToRight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int[] selectedRows = leftTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();
                    for (int row : selectedRows) {
                        int modelRow = leftTable.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                        rightModel.addRow(leftModel.getDataVector().get(modelRow));
                    }
                }
            });

            add(new JScrollPane(leftTable), gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            add(new JScrollPane(rightTable), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;

            JPanel actions = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            actions.add(copyToRight);

            add(actions, gbc);
        }

    }

    public static final String[][] NAMES = new String[][]{
        new String[]{"Laura", "Williams"},
        new String[]{"Andrea", "Ellis"},
        new String[]{"John", "King"},
        new String[]{"Kenneth", "Garcia"},
        new String[]{"William", "Miller"},
        new String[]{"William", "Benitez"},
        new String[]{"Michelle", "Hansen"},
        new String[]{"Nicholas", "Jones"},
        new String[]{"Joshua", "Sanchez"},
        new String[]{"Stephen", "Herring"},
        new String[]{"Kyle", "Wallace"},
        new String[]{"Oscar", "Wong"},
        new String[]{"Shane", "Santana"},
        new String[]{"Jeffrey", "Weber"},
        new String[]{"Laura", "Hale"},
        new String[]{"Dr.", "Henry"},
        new String[]{"Tammy", "Mathis"},
        new String[]{"Jennifer", "Rodriguez"},
        new String[]{"Joshua", "Tucker"},
        new String[]{"Alejandra", "Wong"},
        new String[]{"Barbara", "Flores"},
        new String[]{"Kristin", "Sims"},
        new String[]{"Stephanie", "Green"},
        new String[]{"Travis", "Parks"},
        new String[]{"Brian", "Meyers"},
        new String[]{"Haley", "Casey"},
        new String[]{"Laura", "Wilson"},
        new String[]{"Sharon", "Berg"},
        new String[]{"Joshua", "Warren"},
        new String[]{"William", "Martin"},
        new String[]{"David", "Ramos"},
        new String[]{"Jessica", "Dennis"},
        new String[]{"Joel", "Ferrell"},
        new String[]{"Michael", "Johnson"},
        new String[]{"Kim", "Watkins"},
        new String[]{"Loretta", "Reed"},
        new String[]{"Jeffrey", "Williams"},
        new String[]{"Jennifer", "Hale"},
        new String[]{"Alicia", "Padilla"},
        new String[]{"Ian", "Wagner"},
        new String[]{"Jasmine", "Wheeler"},
        new String[]{"Cynthia", "Aguilar"},
        new String[]{"Justin", "Flores"},
        new String[]{"Mitchell", "Stephens"},
        new String[]{"Kristi", "Rodriguez"},
        new String[]{"Renee", "Young"},
        new String[]{"Shane", "Simmons"},
        new String[]{"Beverly", "Werner"},
        new String[]{"Jordan", "Townsend"},
        new String[]{"Carrie", "Solomon"},
        new String[]{"Jessica", "Martin"},
        new String[]{"John", "Pearson"},
        new String[]{"Steven", "Miranda"},
        new String[]{"Jennifer", "Knight"},
        new String[]{"Lindsay", "Martinez"},
        new String[]{"Joshua", "Roy"},
        new String[]{"Jerry", "Bailey"},
        new String[]{"Lauren", "Barr"},
        new String[]{"Frank", "Castaneda"},
        new String[]{"Gary", "Franklin"},
        new String[]{"Robert", "Lewis"},
        new String[]{"Peter", "Vasquez"},
        new String[]{"Brittany", "Rich"},
        new String[]{"Jacob", "White"},
        new String[]{"Anna", "Smith"},
        new String[]{"Michelle", "Davis"},
        new String[]{"Cesar", "Frank"},
        new String[]{"Chad", "Walsh"},
        new String[]{"Thomas", "Johnson"},
        new String[]{"Susan", "Wilkerson"},
        new String[]{"Hunter", "Garrett"},
        new String[]{"Molly", "Hernandez"},
        new String[]{"Gary", "Richmond"},
        new String[]{"Megan", "Price"},
        new String[]{"Daniel", "Mack"},
        new String[]{"Margaret", "Andrade"},
        new String[]{"Erika", "White"},
        new String[]{"Laura", "Carr"},
        new String[]{"Robin", "Schultz"},
        new String[]{"Valerie", "King"},
        new String[]{"Jacob", "Sherman"},
        new String[]{"Monique", "King"},
        new String[]{"Laura", "Strickland"},
        new String[]{"Jonathan", "Zuniga"},
        new String[]{"Danny", "Taylor"},
        new String[]{"Darrell", "Reese"},
        new String[]{"Juan", "Watkins"},
        new String[]{"Valerie", "Cohen"},
        new String[]{"David", "Ortiz"},
        new String[]{"Catherine", "Hawkins"},
        new String[]{"William", "Parker"},
        new String[]{"Christine", "Freeman"},
        new String[]{"Corey", "Keller"},
        new String[]{"James", "Hicks"},
        new String[]{"Nicole", "Petty"},
        new String[]{"Alexandria", "Aguirre"},
        new String[]{"Heather", "Kim"},
        new String[]{"Nichole", "Palmer"},
        new String[]{"Jonathan", "Moore"},
        new String[]{"Cynthia", "Gibbs"},};
}
```

Comment: My program is not supposed to copy the selected values but get all the values from a specific row cells but thanks anyway. I might be considering in adding this concept in my program.

Comment: So, then you need to change the title of the question. I’ve demonstrated both a straight “copy” and a “conversation” between models with different structures